# VBScript Class Function with Multiple Parameters

Tags: function, class, vbscript

I have a class function I want to feed multiple parameters but I am having trouble as I am new to using classes in VB.

This is what I currently have working with a single parameter

```
Set objLoc = new Location
objLoc.getLoc = strOffice
```

Need it to work something like this

```
Set objLoc = new Location
objLoc.getLoc = (strOffice, strDep)
```

Location Class

```
Class Location
        Private strPhone, strFax, strStreet, strCSZ
Public Property Let getLoc(strOffice)
    if LCase(strOffice) = LCase("foo") then
        strPhone = "999-999-9999"
        strFax = "888-888-8888 fax"
        strStreet = "..."
        strCSZ = "..."
    ElseIf  LCase(strOffice) = LCase("bar") then
        strPhone = "777-777-7777"
        strFax = "555-555-5555 fax"
        strStreet = "..."
        strCSZ = "..."
    Else
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get Street
    Street = strStreet
End Property

Public Property Get CSZ
    CSZ = strCSZ
End Property

Public Property Get Fax
    Fax = strFax
End Property

Public Property Get Phone
    Phone = strPhone
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: what is getLoc?  is it a class or a string?

Comment: why not paste your Location class

Comment: Location class Pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't SET a property with more than 1 value, you need a Subroutine to set both OR you need to add a new property for the other value.

So, option #1 (add a sub):  (not a vbScript expert but have years of VB.NET and VB:

```
Public Sub SetOfficeAndDept(office,dept)
   ... code ...
End Sub
```

option #2, (add a new property):

```
Public Property Let Dept(d)
    Dept = d
End Property
```

option #3, (add a new constructor)

```
Public Sub New(office, dept)
      ..set your vars...
End Sub
```

to use it:

```
Set l = new Location(ofc,dept)
```